# background image won't repeat full height

Tags: html, css

[Here](http://www.technorent.lv/tehnikas-noma-ar-operatoru) you can see my problem. Background image is set to repeat whole height, but it not working as wanted.

My CSS

```
#wrapper {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;

    background: url(img02.jpg) repeat-x left top;
}
```

I tried to add theese lines

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #F7F7F7 url(img01.jpg) repeat left top;
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #5A554E;

/* theese lines added*/ 
        min-height:100%;
      height:auto;

}
```

But still the background image won't repeat all height.

Comment: You only set repeat-x, which tells it to repeat on the x-axis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only set repeat-x, which tells it to repeat on the x-axis, however making this kind of gradient image repeat results in quite an ugly background. Instead i recomend doing it all with css if possible.

One of many helpful tools to generate CSS gradients: 
http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Answer (score -1):

If you want to stretch the background to fill the page, use:

```
background-size: 100%;
```

Otherwise, if you want to repeat it, use Erik's answer.